# Org-mode: Inserting (advanced) LaTeX equations for HTML expot

Tags: emacs, html, latex, org-mode

I'm using `org-mode` as working environment, and so far has been extremely useful.

One of the wonders of it is the versatility of exporting... I can export to LaTeX or HTML or ODT files from the same code. :-)

However, I would like to be able of writing an `aling` LaTeX environment and get it exported properly to HTML.

I've tried different form, but nothing!

For example: the code returns nothing

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX   
  \begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x' \\ y' \\ z'
    \end{pmatrix} 
    = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      R11 & R12 & R13\\
      R21 & R22 & R23\\
      R31 & R32 & R33
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      X \\ Y \\ Z
    \end{pmatrix}   
  \end{align}
#+END_LaTeX
```

Any ideas?... Thanks!

Comment: What commands have you tried to convert this?

Comment: @slm Direct HTML export from org-mode with the keybind `C-c C-e h o`

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That is not the same question, and additionally it's a different group!

Comment: Can you please explain org-mode, I'm not familiar, so I would assume others don't as well.

Comment: @slm [org-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) is an Emacs package. If you don't know what it is, you aren't in this question's audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Try placing your cursor inside the equation and hit `C-c C-x C-l`.

This is the default shortcut for org-preview-latex-fragment. `C-c C-x C-l` will generate the preview and `C-c C-c` will revert to your original code. You can also type `M-x org-preview-latex-fragment`. And if you ever forget, just hit the [TAB] key anytime after hitting M-x to get a list of possible commands. You can also hit `C-g` to cancel everything out.

[Here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) is a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We like answers to be a bit more detailed. Could you explain what this does and why it should work or otherwise flesh this answer out?

Comment: Sure, no problem. This is the default shortcut for `org-preview-latex-fragment`. `C-c C-x C-l` will generate the preview and `C-c C-c` will revert to your original code. You can also type `M-x org-preview-latex-frament`. And if you ever forget, just hit the [TAB] key anytime after hitting M-x to get a list of possible commands. You can also hit C-g to cancel everything out. [Here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) is a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant [edit] your answer and include that information. The comments are ephemeral and can be deleted without warning.